# Entire VPS locks up when using particular theme

Tags: themes, vps

I have a VPS with, so far 2 osCommerce websites, and it was running fine.  I then installed Wordpress 3.4.1 and it was fine as well.  I tried a free theme from the theme installer called Hero, and every 30 or so page loads the entire VPS locks up.  Not just the apache or PHP or MySQL, but I can't even access the server via SSH.  This is on a test server with 2gb of ram and almost no other visits than my own.

Theme: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/hero

Comment: What stories to the server logs tell thee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the first step is to make sure there is no problem by changing the theme to Twenty Eleven and running the 'same steps' to recreate the problem.

Some themes may not be ready for Wordpress 3.4.1 as it introduced a lot of theme related changes. So see if there is anything on the WordPress.org page for your theme of on the theme developers website.

Failing that you can ...

1. download again the theme from WordPress.org, in case your zip was corrupt
2. choose another theme
3. contact the theme developer via the theme page on WordPress if you really want to use that theme